# Why am I receiving an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

In my JAVA code, I am given a data and I have to find the mode. Everything successfully compiled, and every method works. However, when I try to access the mode, I get an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 987` in my terminal window. The highlighted portion is in the following method, which is one of my max methods. The data array, by the way, is just `int []` data.

```
public int maxOfData(int [] oa)
{
    int max = oa[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (oa[i] > max)
        max = oa[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

The exception is on the line `if(oa[i] > max)`

And the mode code is this:

```
public int[] modeOfData()
{
    int[] tally = new int[maxOfData() + 1];

    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      tally[data[i]]++;
    } 

    //max contains frequency of modes
    int max = maxOfData (tally);

    int count = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < tally.length; i++)
    {
        if( tally[i] == max )
           count++;
    }
    //count occurence of maxValue in tally (for)
    //that determines how many modes there are

    //declare another int called modes
    int[] modes = new int[count];
    //size of array should be count

    //loop through tally and extract modes: it's the index value.

    int pos = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < tally.length; i++)
    {
       if(tally[i] == count)
          modes[pos++] = i;
    }

    return modes;

    //modes are where the values are == max
}
```

My other max for `data` is the same but `data` instead of `oa`. I need both max methods, just like that, according to my teacher. So what do I do? How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by access mode? The function call modeOfData()?

Comment: what **size** refers to ?

Comment: in `maxOfData(int [] oa)` check boundary condition for the array. also what is `size`?

Comment: size in maxOfData is not declared - why pasting code that should not compile?

Answer (score 1):

I think the line

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i = 1; i < oa.length; i++)
```

Comment: what about the index '0'

Comment: if this is the problem, why don't just return oa.length instead of return max?

Comment: max is the contents of the array, not the length of the array

Comment: @RafaEl - The array isn't sorted. The max element is not necessarily at the end. Besides, `oa[oa.length]` is _guaranteed_ to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (or `NullPointerException` if `oa` is `null`).

Answer (score 0):

ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception is thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array. Whenever you iterate an Array object. you need to iterate while checking the index is always lesser than its length

for example,

```
    for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){
    //access array content in ith position
    System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

Your size variable has the value of an illegal array index. that's the problem

Comment: before looping the OP assigns oa[0] to max, it is not necessary to start at 0

Answer (score 0):

Look at the number stored into size and then check to see what size you declared `oa[]` to be. If size is bigger than the size of `oa[]` then you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this part of code

```
int max = oa[0];

for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    if (oa[i] > max)

    max = oa[i];
}
```

rewrite the method `maxOfData(int [] oa)` with proper checks like this

```
  public int maxOfData(int[] oa) {
    if (oa == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input array is null");
    }
    int max=oa[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < oa.length; i++) {
            if (oa[i] > max)
                max = oa[i];
        }
    return max;
}
```

if input array is null it should not be processed.

Comment: In OP's code, we don't know what `size` is. It may be less than `oa.length`, which would mean that your code would be computing something different than intended.

Comment: agreed, it could be size of heap(heap represented as array) elements in the array. Additional checks can be applied for that but for the given problem nothing is said about `size` variable

Comment: Personally I think the above code is messy.  a) no `else if` needed  b) as OP did. Assign oa[0] to max, then loop is clean and easy to follow.

Comment: still you do not need `if (oa.length > 1) {`  Remove that as you basically have the same answer as me.